# Configuration with name 'default' not found - document picker

Tags: react-native

I want to use this library:

```
react-native-document-picker
```

https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker

I follow these steps:

```
npm i --save react-native-document-picker

react-native link
```

I want to run my project on android device:

```
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
   > Configuration with name 'default' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

everything work fine before install it.

I don't know where is my problem and I dont know how can I solve it!

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-document-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-contacts')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

setting.gradle:

```
include ':react-native-document-picker'
project(':react-native-document-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-document-picker/android')
include ':react-native-contacts'
project(':react-native-contacts').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-contacts/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')

include ':app'
```

MainApplication.java:

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
        new ReactNativeDocumentPicker(),
        new ReactNativeContacts(),
        new VectorIconsPackage()
  );
}
```

Comment: did you add this line in *android/app/build.gradle*: `compile project(':react-native-document-picker')`

Comment: @Cherniv yes. I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a pro in this, but this is what i found from the test I did.

Unfortunately, `npm i --save react-native-document-picker` uninstalls all other packages in the project. So after executing `npm i --save react-native-document-picker`,

1. execute `npm install` again. It'll install the missing packages. then
2. execute `react-native link` to link the library.
3. Then open the android project directory with `Android Studio`. It'll suggest you to upgrade the gradle version. Accept it , and rebuild the project.

That's it. Working source code can be found from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BTcPWKyrA_KK0fcoYOgS0hHhcReOckE8)

Let me know if it worked for you.